# WPF Datagrid Click annoyance Xaml

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, datarow

I have a WPF datagrid that is defined as this in XAML

```
      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
      AutoGeneratingColumn="dgData_AutoGeneratingColumn"
      CheckBox.Checked="dgData_Checked"
      CheckBox.Unchecked="dgData_UnChecked"
      FrozenColumnCount="2"
      VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
```

At runtime I have a datatable (with a column "IsDirty" and about 10 boolean columns) bound to the datagrid. The column IsDirty is used for a dirty marker, here is its DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dtIsDirty">
    <Grid>
        <Image Margin="2"
            Source="{DynamicResource imgDirtyRow}"
            Visibility="{Binding Path=Item.IsDirty,
                                 Mode=OneWay,
                                 TargetNullValue=Collapsed,
                                 Converter={StaticResource cnvBooleanToVisibilityConverter},
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"
            />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

All works ok: If I check/uncheck a checkbox, the row's dirty marker is displayed.

But when I enter a row before changing a checkbox in this row, the flag is not displayed directly but when I leave the row.

Setting the binding's UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChange in the DataTemplate does not help, neither does settings the column's binding's UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChange.

Any clue what I can do?

Regards